# Vue 3 How do I properly use a pinia store in another pinia store?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have a `todosStore` pinia store that performs actions (CRUD operations) against the backend. In this todosStore, I need to use another pinia store `bannerStore` for updating the bootstrap alert component's message and class in the template.

If I use the bannerStore in the todosStore.js like below, I get the following error `Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Are you trying to use a store before calling "app.use(pinia)"?`

```js
import { useBanner } from "./bannerStore";

const bannerStore = useBanner()

export const useTodos = defineStore("todos", {
    state: () => ({
        ...
    }),
    actions: {
            },
})
```

If I use the store inside each action like below, then it works properly.

```js
export const useTodos = defineStore("todos", {
    state: () => ({
        todos: [],
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchAllTodos() {
            try {
                const res = await todoService.getAllTodos()
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    this.todos = res.data
                }
            } catch (error) {
                const bannerStore = useBanner()
                bannerStore.setBanner(`Failed to retrieve all todos: ${error}`, 'error')
            }
        },
        async addTodo(todo) {
            const bannerStore = useBanner()
            try {
                const res = await todoService.addTodo(todo)
                if (res.status === 201) {
                    this.todos.push(todo)
                    bannerStore.setBanner("Todo added successfully!", 'success')
                }
            } catch (error) {
                bannerStore.setBanner(`Failed To add todo item ${todo}: ${error}`, 'error')

            }
        },
        async deleteTodoById(todoId) {
            const bannerStore = useBanner()
            try {
                const res = await todoService.deleteTodo(todoId)
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    this.todos = this.todos.filter(t => t.id !== todoId)
                    bannerStore.setBanner(`Successfully deleted todo with Id ${todoId}`, 'success')
                }
            } catch (error) {
                bannerStore.setBanner(`Failed operation: deleteTodoById() for id ${todoId}: ${error}`, 'error')
            }
        }
    },
```

I would like to know if what I am currently doing (initializing bannerStore in each action) is the optimal way of doing it, or if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd method is correct. Even if you call `useStore` a million times, it will only do one thing: return the initialized store. You may not use `useStore` at the startup thread because of `pinia` not yet attached to the component.

If you're worried about it use the nice composition API syntax

```js
export const useTodos = defineStore("todos", () => {
    const todos = reactive([])
  const banner = useBannerStore()
    

  function addTodo() {

  }

  return { todos, addTodo }
})
```